# Pointers for dummies

Tags: c, function, pointers

I just learned pointers and I wrote a very simple program to check out if what I understood is correct; my idea is to create a simple functions that gets as an input a integer value and returns its address.

Even though this should be the easiest thing on earth I get a warning message after compiling and I don't know why....

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// returnType functionName(type arg1, type arg2)
int* return_me(int);

int main(){
    int  x = 1;
    int *p;

    p = &x;
    printf("p: %p\n", p);

    p = return_me(x);
    printf("p: %p\n", p);

    return 0;
}

int* return_me(int num){
     return &num;
}
```

I should get the same result but I don't... where am I messing up?

Here's the warning:

```
pointers.c: In function ‘return_me’:
pointers.c:21:2: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
return &num;
```

Comment: First step towards a good question: besides saying you got a warning message, also **post the warning message**.

Comment: the local variable num is not at the same memory location as the variable x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had re-written your code here. There was a bit modification.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// returnType functionName(type arg1, type arg2)
int* return_me(int*);

int main(){
int  x = 1;
int *p;

p = &x;
printf("p: %p\n", p);

p = return_me(&x);
printf("p: %p\n", p);

return 0;
}

int *return_me(int *num){
 return num;
}
```

On my System when i executed the above code i got the following outpu

```
p: 0x7fff4e0305ec
p: 0x7fff4e0305ec
```

With pictorial representation

```
  X         P        num
+----+    +----+    +----+
| 1  |    |1000|    |1000|
+----+    +----+    +----+
 1000      2000      3000
Fig: 1a,1b,1c respectively.
```

The code

```
int x=1;
```

Refer to fig 1a.

The code

```
p=&x;
```

Refer to fig 1b.

The Code

```
int *return_me(int *num){
```

Where the num is holding the value shown in fig 1c.

Same value is returned to the main function also.

**The problem with your code was, you are using the copie of variable x(i.e, call by value) but not the actual address of the variable x (which is done using call by reference).
when you send the copie of x then the life time of the variable will be with in the function where it is declared. The life of the variable is considered to be dead when control leaves the function (i.e, main() ), in your case.**

Answer (score 9):

The line

```
p = return_me(x);
```

is assigning the value of `x` to the variable `num` in the function, similarly to this:

```
int num = x ;
p = &num ;
```

`num` is a different variable, and has a different address.

Also note that when you return its address from a function the local variable `num` doesn't exist anymore and printing its address is not really defined.

Something like this:

```
int* return_me( int* pnum )
{
     printf("%d" , *pnum ) ;
     return pnum ;
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that there is no way of creating a function that does whati'm trying to do?

Comment: @FedericoGentile You should pass the address in the first place. Dereferencing in the function will give you the value.

Comment: mmm... if i pass the address first then the return_me function becomes useless since it doesn't do anything basically... my goal is to create a function that get as an input a random integer and to get it's address as an output... i now understand that the num and x addresses get mixed but i just can't figure out how to solve this problem

Comment: @FedericoGentile I think it is possible, you should really ask a new question as that is a different problem.

Comment: @FedericoGentile: There's no good way to define a function that does what you want; the formal parameter will always be a different object in memory from the actual parameter.  You could define a macro like `#define RETURN_ME(x) &(x)`, although it's not very useful, and it assumes `x` will always have an address (not the case if `x` is a numeric literal or an expression that isn't an lvalue).

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that a parameter in c is ALWAYS copy by value.
Therefore you can only instantiate a new int and copy the value to it `num`.

```
int x = 1;       // x is an int
int* p = &x;    // p is a pointer to an int

return_me(x)     // here you pass the integers value as "copy by value"
```

Inside `return_me()`

```
int* return_me(int num){    // here you instantiate a new int "num" and copy the value from "x" to it.
     return &num;           // therefore you have a new Int and a new a new address which is different from "i" outside this func
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an integer as your x to a function, the function does not get the address where your x resides. Instead it just gets access to its value. The compiler usually passes such value by either assigning it's value to some register, or by pushing it on the stack. Either way, the called function can NOT make any assumptions about its location. Rather it can only use its VALUE. If and when a function is expected to know a certain variable's address, it is usually because it is an OUT argument, meaning the called function should manipulate the value, and project it back to the calling function, and in such case, the calling function should instead pass a pointer to that variable, rather than it's value.

Answer (score 0):

You cant find the address of just any random integer in C without using '&" operator.
The function you are trying to implement is implemented by '&' operator itself.
So you should read about & operator and how it is implemented in C.